# Updating Test Case's Work Product via RallyRestAPI returns error

Tags: rally

I have a C# application that uses the RallyRestAPI version 2.0.1.0 to modify test case information.  One task the tool performs is to update the "WorkProduct" of a test case.  This essentially means associating a User Story to the Test Case.  When I execute the code on my PC in the USA, the association is successful.  When a coworker in Europe runs the same code, Rally returns an error.  That error is, "Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: expected '"' but saw '0'[ chars read = >>>{"testcase":{"WorkProduct":{"_rallyAPIMajor":"2","_rallyAPIMinor":"0","_ref":...".

I don't understand why the coworker receives an error, but I do not.  The application uses an API key, so I know it is not an access issue.  I also know that Rally is finding the correct test case and user story to update because during debugging, the _ref property is identical regardless of which person attempts to update the test case.  Lastly, I confirmed the coworker is able to use the tool to update other test case information such as "Name" and "Notes".

```
DynamicJsonObject toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();
Request requestWorkProdcut = new Request("HierarchicalRequirement");
requestWorkProdcut.Project = rallyProjectRef;
requestWorkProdcut.ProjectScopeDown = false;
requestWorkProdcut.ProjectScopeUp = false;
requestWorkProdcut.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, newValue);
QueryResult findWPMatchQueryResult = m.myRestApi.Query(requestWorkProdcut);
toUpdate["WorkProduct"] = findWPMatchQueryResult.Results.First();
OperationResult updateOperationResult = m.myRestApi.Update(currentTestCaseRef, toUpdate);
```

Comment: hmm.  that sounds like an encoding problem to me.  what operating system/language is your coworker using?

Comment: also, try to remove this from the VS realm for troubleshooting purposes and see if the same update can be made in the browser REST client or in the terminal using curl. Here is the curl command, where _abc123 is the apikey:                      curl --header "zsessionid:_abc123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d"{\"TestCase\":{\"WorkProduct\":\"/hierarchicalrequirement/35964898408\"}}" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TestCase/38157362317

Comment: For whatever reason, the issue has been resolved.  The user is no longer seeing the error and we cannot recreate it anymore.